# How to place a LinearLayout below a LinearLayout inside another RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Im trying to place à LinearLayout below a LinearLayout inside another RelativeLayout?

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                >

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/background_linearlayout_reportdelay"

                 >
           </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Thank you

Comment: Why? If you only have 2 elements inside the RelativeLayout, you could just replcae it with a vertical LinearLayout. Or if the child LinearLayouts have few elements, ditch the LinearLayout and put them all directly in the RelativeLayout.

Comment: Thanks , i replace RelativeLayout with a vertical LinearLayout ans it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/background_linearlayout_reportdelay" />

        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 20):

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top">

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/background_linearlayout_reportdelay"
                android:layout_below="@+id/layout1">
           </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```