# My scrollview scrolls above the header android

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have a `header` in my layout and and `scrollview`below the header. When I start filling the content in the `scrollview` (so that i get to scroll the page) , the `scrollview` starts scrolling on the top of the header

bucket.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel_rootMyBucketList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_mybuket_list"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bucket_header"
        layout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_1"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_2"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_1"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_3"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_2"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_4"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_3"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_5"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_4"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_6"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_5"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_7"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_6"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_8"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_7"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_9"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_8"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_10"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_9"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_11"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_10"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_12"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_11"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cyan_dark"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_search"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_home_search"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_header_tittle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="Change Password"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_large" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/circle_indicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tv_header_tittle"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#512da8"
        app:fillColor="@color/white"
        app:pageColor="@color/blue"
        app:strokeColor="@color/blue"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bucketlist_next"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txt_medium"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_glob"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_home_globe"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

[image]

Comment: you need to add android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_header" in scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first use `RelativeLayout` (Parent) instead `LinearLayout`.

Then call `android:layout_below` in `ScrollView`

**android:layout_below**

> Positions the top edge of this view below the given anchor view ID.
>   Accommodates top margin of this view and bottom margin of anchor view.

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_header">
```

**Edited**

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_header">
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
       >
```

Comment: dude its a LinearLayout not Relative

Comment: Thanks for mentions . Use `RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout` .

Comment: tried this earlier , but let me make one more attempt

Comment: @karthikkolanji Ji . As your wish .  `RelativeLayout` is very flexible .

Comment: still same results . scrolls on top of the header

Comment: @karthikkolanji Actually its a xml problem .Nothing else . need to rectify .`include` are LinearLayout ?

Comment: .include is also RelativeLayout

Comment: okay add `RelativeLayout` as parent of your `ScrollView` & call `android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_header"`

Comment: add fill_parent (Height) in your parent RL

Comment: @karthikkolanji check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24923227/how-to-place-a-linearlayout-below-a-linearlayout-inside-another-relativelayout

Comment: its already match_parent . I even made header.xml  to match_parent height , still same problem :(

Comment: very strange case . PLease show your `header` layout

Comment: @karthikkolanji Sorry , I was offline . Tell me

Comment: added header.xml . any solution to my problem ? :(

Comment: @karthikkolanji My advice , Please create a another project (Dummy) , Use RL and `android:layout_below`

Comment: looks like this the only attempt left :(. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @karthikkolanji some times it happens . Move ahead .

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_header"
```

to your scrollView

Answer (score 0):

try this ,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel_rootMyBucketList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_mybuket_list"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/bucket_header"
        layout="@layout/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></include>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_header"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_1"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_2"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_1"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_3"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_2"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_4"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_3"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_5"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_4"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_6"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_5"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_7"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_6"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_8"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_7"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_9"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_8"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_10"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_9"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_11"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_10"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>

            <include
                android:id="@+id/bucket_row_12"
                layout="@layout/row_my_bucket"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/bucket_row_11"
                android:visibility="gone"></include>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this in scrollview and try changing your relative layout to linear one.

```
android:fillViewport = "true"
```